# Excel macro to copy content of multiple xml files and paste in excel rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a multiple xml files(eg 100 xml files) in a folder, my requirement is to create a macro to copy the content of the xml files and paste it in excel sheet.

For example: 1st xml file content -> Excel cell A1
             2nd xml file content -> Excel cell A2 and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will look at all xml files in a given folder and then copy the contents to your column A on Sheet1:

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
Dim MyData As String
Dim LastRow As Long
x = 1
LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim StrFile As String
    StrFile = Dir("C:\Users\User3282573\*.xml") 'change this path to your folder path
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        Open "C:\Users\User3282573\" & StrFile For Binary As #1 'also change this path
        MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
        Get #1, , MyData
        Sheet1.Cells(x, 1).Value = MyData
        x = x + 1
        Close #1
        StrFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```